# UIPrintInteractionController not displaying in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm trying to print from an app that runs on both iPhone and iPad. There's no problem with the iPhone part of the printing. However, whenever I hit the print button, I do not get the pop-up to allow me to select the printer and send the job.

The view this is called from is a regular UIView in a navigation controller if that has any bearing.

The button that calls it via IBAction is part of the segmented control, since that seemed to be the best way for me to get three buttons besides the back button in the nav bar. I don't think it's the button because as I said, it works in the iPhone version.

I have verified that it at least thinks it's presenting. I generates and height, width and origin for the pic, but I can't see it. Any help would be terrific as this is the last piece of the puzzle for this app.

Thanks!

```
- (void)printStory
{
    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    pic.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = @"My Great Prompt";
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;

    NSString *msgBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", self.summaryLabel.text, @"\n\n", self.storyEditorTextView.text];


    UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc]
                                                 initWithText:msgBody];
    textFormatter.startPage = 0;
    textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1 inch margins
    textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;
    pic.printFormatter = textFormatter;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
        }
    };

    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [pic presentFromRect:self.view.frame
                      inView:self.view
                    animated:YES
           completionHandler:completionHandler];
        }
    else {
        [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try passing a smaller `rect`. You shouldn't pass in a rect that fills the screen.

Comment: Thanks for this. That seemed to do the trick. It doesn't look like i can mark your comment as an answer, though.

Comment: I posted my comment as a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a smaller `rect`. You can't pass in the `rect` of the view controller's view. The popover is displayed around the perimeter of the passed in rect. If the rect fills the screen, the popover is displayed off of the screen. The rect should be something relatively small like the rect of a button or other small view such that the popover's pointer can touch the edge of the rect and the rest of the popover can fit on the screen.

Comment: Thanks. This totally fixed my issue.

My only other issue is that it crashes when I print, but only in the simulator. iPad printing is actually fine.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please move below code to your .h file.

```
UIPrintInteractionController *pic;
```

Because when the method completes the pic object will be release so may be that cause the issue.

and  the rect you are passing should be the position of your button or segment whatever you use.

Hope this will help you.